# Adding custom app to Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning, builder

I have this one SF account where I successfully added my custom app to the right menu on the Opportunity page.

It looks like this:

[image]

But when I use the exact same settings on another SF account. It looks like this:

[image]

And when I activate the app my custom app is the only thing that shows up on the Opportunity page.

How can I get the Builder to show the Opportunity page like in the first screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at two different pages, notice the API name.

You have to add those components to the Lightning record page if you want it to look the same.

Those components are Highlights Panel, Path, Tabs and Related Lists.

Comment: I didn't do this last time. But it works, kinda. But now it's missing the widgets in the main opportunity page. Where the opportunity details are shown

Comment: I'd rather it use the default settings of the page and me just injecting my app into it.